# xubuntu 12.10 how do shortcuts (technically) trigger actions. Trying to debug shortcut randomly stop working

Tags: shortcut-keys, xubuntu, debugging

Keyboard shortcuts randomly stops working, it appears to primarily affect shortcuts involving the Alt-key.

I have seen this issue in 12.04 as well. I'm now trying to research the issue in more detail, so I'm hoping there is some way to log what happens when a shortcut key combination is pressed.

I'm still very interested in knowing how xubuntu connects a shortcut with its intended action, but I did something that may have solved the issue:

Going through dconf-editor under

org/compiz/integrated/show-hud

I removed the the shortcut "Alt"

The issue hasen't shown up since.

This indicates that the original issue may be triggered by compiz grabbing the alt-key *sometimes*.